# Why can't I import Pod Unit Tests file into host application Unit Tests file

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, xcodeproj

I have a project which depends on a cocoapod dependency, this dependency has a Unit Tests target that contains some mocking files I want to use in the tests of my host application.
Example:

```
@import testable MyPod_Unit_Tests
class HostApplicationTestCase: XCTestCase {
    func setup() {
        let mockObj = UsefulPodMockObject()
....
```

then I get the following building error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/macuser/dev/projs/HostProject/Pods/pod-library/pod-library/Frameworks'
>   ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'RandomCocoapodsDependencyFromPodfile'
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "MyPod_Unit_Tests.UsefulPodMockObject.init() -> MyPod_Unit_Tests.UsefulPodMockObject", referenced from:
>         closure #1 () -> () in HostApplicationUnitTests.HostApplicationTestsCase.spec() -> () in HostApplicationTestsCase.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The podspec file probably does not include them, so they are not exposed to your application.

Comment: Thanks @CodeBender, manipulating the podspec was key to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

First, exclude the mocks folder from the test-spec source files with:

```
test_spec.source_files = 'MyPod/Tests/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
test_spec.exclude_files = 'MyPod/Tests/Mocks'
```

Then, include the new path for the mocks folder in the source files attribute of the main spec:

```
spec.source_files = ['MyPod/Classes/**/*', 'MyPod/Tests/Mocks/**/*']
```

This way we keep our folder organized and the podspec takes care of target ownership, just remember to use this folder location consistently.